# Java - Libgdx : Issue with the condition Else

Tags: java, if-statement, libgdx, conditional-statements

I'm trying to write a condition but the else structure always show me an error:

```
Skin skin;
        skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("default/skin/uiskin.json"));
        réponse = new TextField("", skin);
        réponse.setPosition(stage.getWidth() / 2 - 445, stage.getHeight() / 1 - 1600);
        réponse.setSize(900, 120);
        stage.addActor(réponse);

        if (réponse.getText().equals("riviere")){
            game.setScreen(new Stage1(game));
            music.stop();
        }
        else (!réponse.equals("riviere")){
            ecrireLeTexte = true;
        }
```

Code explanation: I want to make a condtion as if the user enter the good word (riviere) it will lead it to the next screen if not it will verify the boolean of ecrireLeTexte which is drawing the text "not the good word, retry"

Comment: If you want to test a further condition, you have to use `else if`, not simply `else`.

Comment: You're missing a .getText() call, but even disregarding that - if you create a textfield and then straight away check what's in it, will the user have any time to type anything in the textfield?

Comment: yeah I thought about it @immibis but how should I do to check it after they typed ?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the 'if' keyword in front of the 'else' keyword:

```
else if(!réponse.equals("riviere")){
```

That indicates that if the first condition was not passed, it delegates to the second one. There can be multiple 'else if's:

```
if(false){
    // Nope...
} else if(false){
    // Nope...
} else if(true){
    // Success!
}
```

Comment: Or in this case just simply remove the condition after the else statement.